# Training problem, Val loss and accuracy not changing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

In the code provided below, I am trying to map an amplitude (10 values) signal with MNIST digit number (to_categorical).

So I input 10 values which are unique for digits and try to classify the digit.

The problem is that the validation loss and accuracy does not change. The code is reproducible and I am attaching link to the `x_train` and`x_test`.

Please can any one tell me what might be the possible problem in this case.

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    # reshape to be [samples][width][height][channels]
    X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
    X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
    # convert from int to float
    X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
    X_test = X_test.astype('float32')



    num_classes=10
    y_train=to_categorical(y_train,num_classes)
    y_test=to_categorical(y_test,num_classes)


    x_train=(60000,10,1,1)
    y_train=(60000,10)
    x_test=(10000,10,1,1)
    y_test=(10000,10)




input_img = Input(shape=(10,1,1))
x = Flatten()(input_img)
x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(200, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(500, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(200, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
decoded = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)


autoencoder=Model(input_img,decoded)
adam=0.01
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=adam,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

history=autoencoder.fit(x_train, y_train,
                epochs=30,
                batch_size=32, 
                verbose=1,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Please suggest what changes can be made.

The x_train data is [found at](https://c.gmx.com/@895287036250954102/_c_qPwCIQzGr9SKIQeO0xQ).

The x_test data is [available at](https://c.gmx.com/@895287036250954102/kqktcTktS1OZtuIvkxbClg).

The trace is given as

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 106us/step - loss: 2.2495 - acc: 0.1665 - val_loss: 2.2312 - val_acc: 0.1794
Epoch 2/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 90us/step - loss: 2.2275 - acc: 0.1800 - val_loss: 2.2292 - val_acc: 0.1790
Epoch 3/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 90us/step - loss: 2.2217 - acc: 0.1845 - val_loss: 2.2087 - val_acc: 0.1944
Epoch 4/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 90us/step - loss: 2.2184 - acc: 0.1861 - val_loss: 2.2533 - val_acc: 0.1631
Epoch 5/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 90us/step - loss: 2.2152 - acc: 0.1882 - val_loss: 2.2084 - val_acc: 0.1934
Epoch 6/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 90us/step - loss: 2.2139 - acc: 0.1877 - val_loss: 2.2234 - val_acc: 0.1779
Epoch 7/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 91us/step - loss: 2.2125 - acc: 0.1886 - val_loss: 2.2245 - val_acc: 0.1776
Epoch 8/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 91us/step - loss: 2.2107 - acc: 0.1932 - val_loss: 2.2173 - val_acc: 0.1888
Epoch 9/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 90us/step - loss: 2.2113 - acc: 0.1909 - val_loss: 2.2074 - val_acc: 0.1890
Epoch 10/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 91us/step - loss: 2.2097 - acc: 0.1910 - val_loss: 2.1980 - val_acc: 0.1953
Epoch 11/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 90us/step - loss: 2.2081 - acc: 0.1914 - val_loss: 2.2248 - val_acc: 0.1814
Epoch 12/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 93us/step - loss: 2.2089 - acc: 0.1912 - val_loss: 2.2367 - val_acc: 0.1739
Epoch 13/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 90us/step - loss: 2.2076 - acc: 0.1922 - val_loss: 2.2233 - val_acc: 0.1841
Epoch 14/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 91us/step - loss: 2.2063 - acc: 0.1914 - val_loss: 2.2039 - val_acc: 0.1934
Epoch 15/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 91us/step - loss: 2.2065 - acc: 0.1936 - val_loss: 2.2435 - val_acc: 0.1783
Epoch 16/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 92us/step - loss: 2.2053 - acc: 0.1957 - val_loss: 2.2050 - val_acc: 0.1958
Epoch 17/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 93us/step - loss: 2.2048 - acc: 0.1943 - val_loss: 2.2285 - val_acc: 0.1796
Epoch 18/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 94us/step - loss: 2.2038 - acc: 0.1958 - val_loss: 2.2069 - val_acc: 0.1954
Epoch 19/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 94us/step - loss: 2.2034 - acc: 0.1945 - val_loss: 2.2001 - val_acc: 0.2020
Epoch 20/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 93us/step - loss: 2.2030 - acc: 0.1938 - val_loss: 2.2140 - val_acc: 0.1894
Epoch 21/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 94us/step - loss: 2.2028 - acc: 0.1949 - val_loss: 2.2047 - val_acc: 0.1953
Epoch 22/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 93us/step - loss: 2.2016 - acc: 0.1954 - val_loss: 2.2338 - val_acc: 0.1748
Epoch 23/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 94us/step - loss: 2.2017 - acc: 0.1956 - val_loss: 2.2158 - val_acc: 0.1862
Epoch 24/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 93us/step - loss: 2.2010 - acc: 0.1944 - val_loss: 2.2195 - val_acc: 0.1915
Epoch 25/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 94us/step - loss: 2.1997 - acc: 0.1949 - val_loss: 2.2128 - val_acc: 0.1893
Epoch 26/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 93us/step - loss: 2.1994 - acc: 0.1938 - val_loss: 2.2114 - val_acc: 0.1927
Epoch 27/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 93us/step - loss: 2.1983 - acc: 0.1968 - val_loss: 2.2269 - val_acc: 0.1821
Epoch 28/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 94us/step - loss: 2.1992 - acc: 0.1953 - val_loss: 2.2127 - val_acc: 0.1885
Epoch 29/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 94us/step - loss: 2.1980 - acc: 0.1966 - val_loss: 2.2455 - val_acc: 0.1717
Epoch 30/30
60000/60000 [==============================] - 6s 94us/step - loss: 2.1974 - acc: 0.1965 - val_loss: 2.2155 - val_acc: 0.1914
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues I see, the first is the `Input` shape you defined for the model.

MNIST dataset has images with a shape of `(28,28)` and you set it as `(10,1,1)`.

You also use `Flatten` as the first layer of the model where it a flatten operation on a tensor reshapes the tensor to have the shape that is equal to the number of elements contained in tensor non including the batch dimension. You should flatten the output of the convolutional layers to create a single long feature vector.

Here is a better model for your purposes:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Also you should normalize the pixel values of the data before sending it to the model:

```
# convert from integers to floats
train_norm = train.astype('float32')
test_norm = test.astype('float32')
# normalize to range 0-1
train_norm = train_norm / 255.0
test_norm = test_norm / 255.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but as i mentioned in my post, my input is a signal with 10 values which represent each digit in the MNIST set, so (28,28) is not my input size as i don't use images as input.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what you are trying to do here. What are you inputting then if it is not the images?

Comment: I think the first line of the post is quite clear